# Como fazer um lista collapsible?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero criar uma exibição de lista expansível. No meu caso, você pode ver todos os resultados dos testes dos alunos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tente o seguinte:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
      <label>Text box</label>
      <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
</p>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="textOutCollapsible" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
<p id="txtOut">

</p>
</body>

<script>
fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
  .then(function(response) {
return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
var divOut = document.getElementById('txtOut');
var divOutCollapsible = document.getElementById('textOutCollapsible');
var allStudents = myJson.students;
for (var k in allStudents) {
  let txtOut = '';
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  let values = allStudents[k].grades;
  let sum = values.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  let avg = sum / values.length;

  // we add the name as part of the dataset
  listItem.dataset.nombre = allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase();

  txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
  txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
  txtOut += `Average: ${avg}<br />`;
  txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;
  textOutCollapsible += `Average: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;

  listItem.innerHTML = txtOut, textOutCollapsible;
  divOut.appendChild(listItem);
  divOutCollapsible.appendChild(listItem);
}
  });

function search() {
  // Declare variables
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while(item = childs.item(++idx)){
   item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith(prefix) ? 'initial': 'none';
  }
}

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var content = this.nextElementSibling;
if (content.style.display === "block") {
  content.style.display = "none";
} else {
  content.style.display = "block";
}
  });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Mas isso só me dá um botão.
Eu também tentei calcular a média de cada aluno e mostrar os detalhes ao apertar o botão na forma de uma cruz, mas isso me dá números um pouco grandes demais para parecerem verdadeiros. Aqui está uma imagem:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se você tiver idéias sobre como reproduzir o CSS estou interessado :)

Comment: Para que reinventar a roda? Para certas coisas é melhor simplificar. Existem **N** números de frameworks com collapsible implementados.

Comment: @LeAndrade Eu não sabia disso, eu só estou começando com esses idiomas

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada em Bootstrap, Materialize, SemanticUI, UIKit, etc...